# Change the "used UVLayer" in all materials in texture_slot 0

Tags: python, texturing, materials, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

i have a model with multiple materials and i like to change the UV-Map for the texture slot "0" 
I got it to work with only one material:

```
import bpy
bpy.data.materials["Wand_Putz_Weiss02.tif"].texture_slots[0].uv_layer = "UVMap"
```

or like this:

```
import bpy
bpy.context.object.active_material.texture_slots[0].uv_layer = "UVMap"
```

is there an way to change the "used uv layer" in all materials assigned to an object?
thank you very much for your help!

greetings,
simisoad

Answer (score 1):

i got it to work... wrong syntax was the problem :) i not used to program with python.

here is my solution:

```
import bpy
for item in bpy.data.materials:
     for itextures in item.texture_slots:
        if itextures is not None:
            item.texture_slots[0].uv_layer = "UVMap"
```

Comment: This will fail when `item.texture_slots[0] is None` when  there is another texture in a latter texture slot.  Either just check on item 0 and set if non null, or would need to find first non null texture slot and set that.  (The latter would be same as code above, edit  last line to `itextures.uv_layer = "UVMap"` and add a line in if block : `break` to quit the inner for loop.